# How to pass value to SAP smartfield valuehelp filter

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have scenario where I want to pass the value to valuehelp filter when user triggers F4 using sapui5. In below screenshot I want Company name to be filled automatically with dynamic value (based on user selection) when user opens this valuehelp.

Please help me with this scenario.

Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by filled automatically with dynamic value . User still have to make a selection after f4 help is clicked. But to set F4 help, you need to handle this via your metadata and annotations.

Please check this :
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3361e270c62c46c9893eaefb2966d62e